# How to get the JQuery Carousel work in IPhone?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, carousel

I'm using the Modern Carousel tool from here and I've added 6 images and it works great on the web browser:

http://projects.timhuegdon.com/modern-carousel/

However, when I view this page on my IPhone 4.0, the Carousol next/back icons don't get displayed as expected. For example, the Back icon is displayed but there is an extra small image to the right side of it. Why?

How could I resolve this? Or is there any other Carousel tool that I could use to be compatible with IPhone?

Many thanks,

Comment: Are you using safari for your test? Have you tried on ipad? Do you have the same problems?

Comment: yes, IPhone's default browser is safari which is where the problem is. I don't have IPad. I don't think the problem is with Safari as I tested the page with a Safari browser on my PC and it works fine. It's something with the IPhone or the way my page has been configured but I followed exactly what their guideline says.

Comment: Nothing wrong on both my iPad first gen and iPhone Touch last gen, both running IOS5. The UI is not ideal for touch, but works.

Comment: thanks for checking. I also had checked with my IPhone with their own site and it was fine. The problem is when I configure their codes for my page; either something is missing from their code or my configuration is not right (but I had copied line by line...)...still investigating

Comment: If I had to bet, I would check your CSS. Could you propose a link/fiddle ?

Comment: just open that link with an IPhone version 3.0 or 4.0.1, you'll see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't work with IPhone software version of 4.0.1. When I upgraded my software version to 5.0, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Give [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) a try. It should work on iPhone 4.0.1 but it is a little different.